# For loop on BufferedReader.readline() halts program execution without throwing exception

Tags: java, for-loop, while-loop, stream

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    String hostName = "localhost";
    int portNumber = 9000;            
        Socket primarySocket = new Socket(hostName, portNumber);
        PrintWriter out =
            new PrintWriter(primarySocket.getOutputStream(), true);
        BufferedReader in =
            new BufferedReader(
                new InputStreamReader(primarySocket.getInputStream()));

        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

        //main loop
        boolean quit = false;
        while(!quit){
            System.out.println("please enter a message.");
            String userInput = sc.nextLine();
            if (userInput.equals("quit")){
                quit=true;
            }
            out.println(userInput);
            System.out.println("Text was sent to server");

            for(String line = in.readLine(); line != null; line = in.readLine()){
                System.out.println(line);
                System.out.println("This is printed exactly once")
            }

            System.out.println("this line is never reached");
        }
```

This is the code I'm working on. The server is configured to simply echo back anything it receives.

the interaction with the terminal is this:

please enter a message.

message

Text was sent to server

message

This text is printed exactly once

It then stops and never prints "This line is never reached". I've run through the for loop in the eclipse debugger. It simply stops executing as if the program crashed, but no exception is thrown anywhere. I would expect it to print whatever is waiting on the stream, then begin executing the top while loop again, but instead it seems to silently crash or something of the sort.

I originally was using a while loop on readline != null, and it had the same behavior.

Comment: Well, this client reads lines sent by the server until the server closes the stream. So, if the server justs sends one line and doesn't close the stream, the client will wait forever for the next line. If you expect the server to send back one line, why do you use a loop instead of just calling readLine() once?

Comment: I'm just trying to get it off the ground at the moment. It will need to read multiple lines in the future. If the for loop is looping forever, why doesn't it keep printing "This text is printed exactly once" to the terminal? EDIT: nevermind, I get that it's not looping, it's blocking. I guess I'll need a two-threaded system where one writes to the stream and the other reads from it.

Comment: Because readLine() is a blocking method: it waits untile the next line is available (or the stream is closed), and then returns it. Since your server doesn't send anything, the client is locked waiting.

Comment: on the server side, look into outputStream.flush()